# Java and Espresso - Can't type in, needs to supports input methods or is assignable from class: class SearchView

Tags: java, testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to use Espresso fro testing an application with this xml:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/tvLogin"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="myHint"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionNext"
        android:inputType="text" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

And this is the test I tried to run:

```
onView(withId(R.id.tvLogin)).check(ViewAssertions.matches(ViewMatchers.isDisplayed()));
onView(withId(R.id.tvLogin)).perform(typeText("test"));
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Action will not be performed because the target view does not match one or more of the following constraints:
((is displayed on the screen to the user) and (supports input methods or is assignable from class: class android.widget.SearchView))
Target view: "TextInputLayout{id=2131362315, res-name=tvLogin, visibility=VISIBLE, width=831, height=144, has-focus=false, has-focusable=true, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@8241b55, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=39.0, y=39.0, child-count=2}"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `tvLogin` is a `TextInputLayout`, which is also a `LinearLayout`, and so that's why you get the error when you perform `typeText()` on it. Since `typeText()` only works on editable field, and `TextInputEditText` is a descendant of `tvLogin`, you can rewrite the test to use one of the convenient matcher [ViewMatchers.supportInputMethods()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/matcher/ViewMatchers#supportsinputmethods) from Espresso:

```
onView(allOf(supportsInputMethods(), isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.tvLogin))))
    .perform(typeText("test"))
```

Alternatively, you can provide an id for the `TextInputEditText`:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
    android:id="@+id/tvLoginEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi|actionNext"
    android:inputType="text" />
```

And then perform `typeText()` on the editable field instead:

```
onView(withId(R.id.tvLoginEditText))
    .perform(typeText("test"))
```