# Espresso error typing some text into TextInputLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-espresso

I want to test my login UI which contains some TextInputLayout fields , i have set up some code to run but it crashes and throws an error , can anyone please with this issue , i appreciate in advance

- I want to simply type some text into TextInputLayout

```
    @Test
    fun testCaseSimulateLoginOnButtonClick(){
        onView(withId(R.id.loginEmail)).perform(typeText("xxxxxxxx@gmail.com"))
        onView(withId(R.id.loginPassword)).perform(typeText("123456"))
        onView(withId(R.id.loginBtn)).perform(click())
        onView(withId(R.id.drawer)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
```

- This is the error i get

```
Error performing 'type text(xxxxxxxx@gmail.com)' on view 'view.getId() is <2131362123/com.example.app:id/loginEmail>'.
```

Comment: When i write in production code  , i'm able to get or type into editText which is subchild of TextInputLayout which is something like this binding.loginEmail.editText!!.text.toString() , but with espresso testing , i'm not sure how or is it impossible ?

Comment: I could add IDs for edittexts but I wanted to simulate the work in testing as done in production . I guess if nothing works , I would go with your suggestion thank you

Comment: Have you tried this solution to help you entering text on `TextInputLayout`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63209022/java-and-espresso-cant-type-in-needs-to-supports-input-methods-or-is-assigna/63257083#63257083

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't type text in the `TextInputLayout` view, that is just a container. The `TextInputLayout` has a `FrameLayout` as a direct child, and in that `FrameLayout` the first child view is the `EditText` (which you can type into)

You can get the `EditText` in Espresso with some extra matchers (find a view that is a descendant of the base `R.id.text_layout` layout and has a class name that ends with `EditText`).

```kotlin
onView(
    allOf(
        isDescendantOfA(withId(R.id.text_layout)),
        withClassName(endsWith("EditText"))
    )
).perform(
    typeText("Hello world")
)
```

If you have to do this in a lot of places, you can write a helper function

```kotlin
fun isEditTextInLayout(parentViewId: Int): Matcher<View> {
    return allOf(
        isDescendantOfA(withId(parentViewId)),
        withClassName(endsWith("EditText"))
    )
}
```

and use it as

```kotlin
onView(isEditTextInLayout(R.id.text_layout)).perform(typeText("Hello world"))
```

for an XML that looks like

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_layout"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Type words here"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Some of the required imports for this to work are

```
import androidx.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.*
import org.hamcrest.Matcher
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.allOf
import org.hamcrest.Matchers.endsWith
```

Of course, you could also just add an `android:id` for the `EditText` and get it that way too...

Comment: I have tried your code , but in the last part where it is written endsWith("") , it has a red line below it ( there is an error )

Comment: Have you imported the right `endsWith` and `withClassName` methods?

Comment: Oh you are correct , the thing is that i had the import Mockito* which actually wrapped in everything after removing and importing the endsWith() on its own , it worked ,Thank you

Comment: Mate i have a quick question if you dont mind , if i have to test third party libraries like Picasso and CircleImageView and so on , what should i use , Thank you

Comment: You might want to ask a separate question, the answer would depend on how you are using them. I usually try to hide those behind some mockable interface and use that interface for my tests, but it depends how you are using it.

Comment: What i basically mean is that it is possible to test them with espresso or it requires a different one (  i read about Ui Automator but i'm not sure about it )

Comment: Again, it depends on how you are using them and how your tests are set up. Espresso is meant for testing view interactions, so you can certainly click on views that they provide. If your clicking action triggers Picasso to do something in the background you would need to make sure your test environment has a suitable test backend for it to use. But again, it really depends on how you are using them.

Comment: Alright mate , it is clear and thank you for taking the time to answer my question . Appreciated